# Lazy load dynamic component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, es6-promise

How can I do something like this?

```
/*
 * @param string component
 * @param callback
 */
function load(component, callback) {
    return import(component).then(jsx=>callback.call(this, jsx)).catch(err=>console.log(err));
}
```

I want to load JSX components from server without defining it in my script anywhere.

I'll create those components as chunks from current project and then remove the relevant code with that one.

I need to load these components by their URL/filename and store them in an object.

Is there any way to achieve something similar to this?

Comment: try using some npm modules which does similar work. for react you can try
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-load-script